# foreach traversing matching conditions stored in a variable

Tags: shell-script, csh

I'm using foreach to retrieve subfolder names that matches a_condition*, following works fine:

```
foreach i (a_condition*)
    echo $i
end
```

It will print 
a_condition1
a_condition2
...

But when I try not hard code a_conditon* like:

```
set condition = a_condition*
foreach i ($condition)
   echo $i
end
```

It will only print the first value, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all the implementations/versions of `csh` that I know:

```
set condition = a_condition*
```

is the same as:

```
set condition = (a_condition*)
```

That is it creates an array containing all the filenames resulting from the expansion of the `a_condition*` glob. I checked with the original 1979 `csh` implementation in 2BSD on a PDP11 emulator, and it was the same there.

The behaviour you describe looks as if that line was interpreted as

```
set condition = a_condition1 a_condition2 a_condition3...
```

That is, defining `condition` as a variable with value `a_condition1` and a variable called `a_condition2`, then one called `a_condition3`... I don't know of any `csh` implementation that behaves like that and I would find it unlikely that such an implementation exists given that the original implementation didn't, but in case it is, you could try doing:

```
set condition = (a_condition*)
```

to see if that makes a difference. That would also be more self-descriptive.

In any case, if you do want that glob to be expanded at the time of assignment and the loop to loop over the elements, the syntax should be:

```
set condition = (a_condition*)
foreach i ($condition:q)
  echo $i:q
end
```

And if you want `condition` to contain the `a_condition*` *string*, and that string to be expanded as a glob at the time of the loop, that would be:

```
set condition = 'a_condition*'
foreach i ($condition)
  echo $i:q
end
```